# How to update an excel file keeping the file open using java?

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

Is there any possibility of having an excel file open and simultaneously when you run a java application to update the same excel file which is open and the changes need to be updated.I tried all the possible ways but I am not figuring out how to update data to an open excel file.

Comment: If you are using poi, then it is not possible. Use these links for explanations
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22932395/apache-poi-and-excel  and  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12938509/poi-cannot-write-to-file-while-it-is-opened-in-excel

Comment: "update the same excel file which is open": OK, what happens if a Excel file is "open"? Then the file has been read by an Application which is running in a operating system. Mostly this application will lock the file. But even if not, any changes to the file will be overridden if the application will rewrite the file. So what you need is **not** updating the file but updating the representation of the file within the application. So you need to control the application using Java.